# Replacing "\\n" in string Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have the following piece of code:

```
String text = "Category:Bishopsq\\nxof La2on</target></link></sentence>\\n</paragraph><paragraph>".toString().replaceAll("(\n|\\n)", "").trim().replaceAll("\\<.*?>", " ").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").trim().replaceAll(" +", " ").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(text);
```

I get the following output:

```
category bishopsq nxof la on n
```

However, I want the following output:

```
category bishopsq xof la on
```

It is not correctly replacing all `\\n`.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you calling toString() on a String?

Comment: for formatting purpose. This is just an abstract of my code and not my entire code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to escape the sign `\`, like this:

```
replaceAll("(\\n|\\\\n)", "")
```